# Bottle access POST IO object?

Tags: python, curl, request, http-post, bottle

I am posting a file to my Bottle server, like so:

```
$ echo hello > foo.txt
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @foo.txt \
      http://localhost:8089/api/noun
```

#### Server

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from bottle import Bottle, request

app = Bottle()


@app.post('/api/noun')
def add_noun():
    return {'files': request.POST.allitems()}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=8089)
```

Using `request.POST.allitems()`, `request.POST.keys()`, or similar seems like a hacky way of accessing the payload. `request.files` equivalent are empty.

Currently I'm putting everything into a `StringIO` object and incrementally iterating over that.

is there a way of access the IO object directly, so I can use `next(it)` and whatever?

Comment: Just curious: why are you using `application/json` (when you're not sending json)?

Answer (score 0):

`request.POST.allitems()` doesn't seem [to be documented](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html), which I assume is the reason you feel it's hacky.(?)

If so, would `request.params` (which is [documented](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.params)) be more to your taste?

```
@app.post('/api/noun')
def add_noun():
    return {'files': request.params.items()}
```

Comment: Thanks, but even `request.params.iteritems()` isn't returning the iterator I want. For one, the `key` has the contents, (and the `value` is empty). Finally, the `key` may contain a huge payload, is there a way to chunk it line-by-line?

Comment: Seems to be returning exactly what it should.  What are you expecting?  Yes, the key has the contents and the value is empty, because the file you're POSTing has only "hello" in it.  Try this and see if it helps elucidate: `echo 'hello=123&goodbye=456' > foo.txt`

Comment: Hmm, you're right; that works. So my actual problem is `POST`ing large CSV files, and rather than load the entire CSV file into memory I want to do line-by-line iteration.

Comment: Ah, check out FileUpload.save ([here's](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#file-uploads) an example). It'll save the uploaded file to disk (efficiently) and you can then read it line by line or however you'd like.  Hope this helps!